# inserting value of map to string

Tags: dart

I took a look at the [postgresql driver dokumentation](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/postgresql). I found the following code there.

```
conn.query('select color from crayons where id = @id', {'id': 5})
  .toList()
    .then((result) { print(result); });

conn.execute('insert into crayons values (@id, @color)',
             {'id': 1, 'color': 'pink'})
    .then((_) { print('done.'); });
```

I wanted to test the inserting of the id into the string and put the following code into [try.dart.org](https://try.dartlang.org/)

```
// Go ahead and modify this example.

void main() {
var string = 'select color from crayons where id = @id', {'id': 5};
  print(string);
}
```

Unfortunately this gives me the following error `Compilation failed: Expected identifier, but got '{'.`. I also tried a few abbreviations but nothing helped.

So the question is. How do I properly insert the values of a map into a string?

Comment: DartPad is a way better option to try and share Dart code https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b90ddbe86db7d366497a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example code from the PostgreSQL driver means that the `query()` method expects two arguments, a string and a map.

Your 2nd example seems to try to do string interpolation. In Dart this would look like

```
var id = 5;
var string = 'select color from crayons where id = $id'; // or ${id}
  print(string);
```

Please don't try this for SQL. This opens a big hole for SQL injection attachs.

PostgresSQL does it's own string interpolation in a safe way.